# quartz.net cron trigger

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

i have a problem with using cron trigger in Quartz.net. My code:

```
        var trigger = new CronTrigger("0/30 * * * * ?");

        trigger.Name = "some name";
        trigger.Group = "group";

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetails, trigger);
```

it should run every 30 seconds, but on last line following exception occures:
"Based on configured schedule, the given trigger will never fire."
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post more code on your trigger setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameters to create a CronTrigger is never a cron expression but the trigger name.
Instead you can use this overload:

```
var trigger = new CronTrigger(triggerName, groupName, "0/30 * * * * ?");
```

UPDATE:

You can [configure](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_10.html) a logger which is used by Quartz.net to trap some internal error.
I used NLog and it has helped me a lot to debug common mistakes.

Comment: i just can't believe it.. i think i had a mental block

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 0,30 * * * * ?

Your way is correct but this alternative might work

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Answer (score -1):

The cron trigger according to the CronMaker site should be: `0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *` 
But your expression seems alright too according to the site.

A convenient site to create cron expressions is [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).